# when publishing from excel to azure how to add all items in azure boards including items other than default 6 items

Tags: excel, azure, azure-devops

I have connected my azure boards to excel sheet but when I publish my data from excel to azure only the default values(ID, Title, Work Item type, State, Reason, Assigned To) are added. I have edited my boards and added more detailed values to it which I wanted to be taken from excel when I publish to boards but each time I try I am not able to connect my additional details(values) from excel to Azure Devops Board.

Is there a way to do that or just a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

You must choose the additional colums via the "Team" Ribbon, "Choose Columns" from the predefinied colums list.
The columns added to excel this way will get updated in AzureDevops / TFS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have already did that, But this didn't worked for me.

Thanks Though